# Reparing a Chinese power supply Unit

Tags: transistors, switch-mode-power-supply, npn

My Chinese phone usb charger has gone.

I opened the lid to repair it, and this is how it looks like (picture below).
Actually how it looked like after I removed Q1 for testing.

[image]

I suppose it has been gone. I checked with the multimeter and all pin combinations are open. And since both transistors were named as Q1 so I removed the second transistor and ensure it's a actually what I think (NPN transistor). But the problem is these two transistors are not identical in their label. I think originally this was designed as identical but later customized it in a later review.

So is it safe to assume that it's also NPN transistor?

This is the transistor that needs to be replaced. And it's a `13001 S 8D`, and the second transistor is , `S9014 C331`.

[image]

What I want to figure out is an alternative.

This transistor is available on [ebay](http://www.ebay.de/itm/5x-Transistor-13001-S-8D-NPN-1250mW-600V-/180969622812).

Could somebody please recommend me a equivalent transistor for this?
Possibly a 1250 mW 600 V one.

If I just put some of those C945 what will happen?

There are no schematics available on this.

--Thanks in advance--

Comment: It isn't worth tying to repair it. Just replace it with a new one.

Comment: Why is that? @Brain Carlton. I suppose only that transistor was gone.

Comment: @sandundhammika Brian is probably trying to tell you that your ability to buy just that one part + shipping will likely approach the cost of buying a new USB wall-wart charger.  If you don't produce in bulk it's normally hard to get a single component for a reasonable price, and USB chargers are produced in such absurd quantities these days that they're very cheap.  Especially since many places (like Amazon) give you free shipping, where most part distributors will not.  I don't have a good suggestion on what part to replace it with, but I'm with Brian.  Though if you don't have 1.85 euro...?

Comment: Quick follow-up: was it that the transistor was the bad part? Or was it that the transformer is delivering voltage spikes which are just a bit above the expected value which caused the transistor to burn out? Or is it that the capacitor is bad? You can replace the transistor. Then find out that it was also the cap, and replace that. Then find out that it really was the transformer which broke everything! Is it worth the time and investment for a [$0.60](http://www.amazon.com/USB-AC-Power-Adapter-White/dp/B0038HYPZS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1355980169&sr=8-1&keywords=usb+charger) part?

Comment: Yes it's even more cheaper to spend $0.60 anyway. But I need this experience. 
I want to make it work back.

Comment: And yes transistor is the bad part. I have checked both transistors. The above removed one is gone.

Comment: @sandundhammika Like I said, yes, the transistor is *now* bad, but the cause of that failure might not just be that it was a bad part, but because there's something fundamentally flawed with the design of the charger.  Either way, like I said when I started, I don't actually have any useful advice on the question you asked so I'll bow out at this point.  Good luck with the repair! (note: I don't think you're being greedy, I was saying it as a matter of practicality; Many people assume repairs are cheaper when they are not)

Comment: Yes, @KitScuzz , and thanks. I could learn something new from this. And for the phone for just now I could buy a new one.

Comment: @sandundhammika You don't have to order a new part online. Collect some discarded electronics and find parts inside.

Comment: @sandundhammika if you really want to learn, why don't you create a schematic from the PCB and find out the configuration your damaged transistor is in. Then it will be easy to recommend a replacement. I believe you will learn a lot using this approach.

Comment: Slightly off topic: Funny to see how they made the PSU even cheaper than the original design: They replaced the full diode bridge with a single diode. I'd be curious for the diagram as @ChetanBhargava proposes :o)

Comment: Yes schematic! I'm working on it. I'll share it with you guys too as soon as possible.

Comment: BEWARE that even a transistor with approximately the same part number may not have the same pinout!  I've seen at least two pinout variations of To-92 13001's in similar chargers.  I'd not recommend repairing this.

Comment: @jippie No full diode bridge? Then what is that four-pin rectangular part below the transformer?

Comment: Its an opto-isolator.  This is a fairly typical switching power supply for this application, and is nothing like the circuit you are mistakenly assuming and basing your DANGEROUS recommendations upon.

Comment: @Kaz as Chris states, this is an opto-isolator. It is used to close the feedback loop while keeping the output galvanic separate. The primary side is usually a high frequency chopper, the secondary site little more than rectifier and buffer cap.

Comment: How are windings of the transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To be as close to the original equipment**, I recommend that you should buy the replacement transistor from ebay, it is not that expensive. As you are not greedy, the price should be ok and you get the joy of replacing it yourself.

Joy of fixing your own charger is priceless.
Happy holidays.

Comment: I finally repair this with the original transistor. It's just 6/- Rs in local shops,and it's about 0.04$ . It's working now. I open this originally learning it. BTW it's more cheaper to repair this.

Comment: @sandundhammika I'm glad that you were able to repair it by yourself and saved the charger from ending up in landfill. Keep it up.

Comment: I just not only repair it,I did some modifications to it's amstrong osicallator to change it's operating frequency, so I could get more power without changing the transformer. 

Transistor blast like a bomb. Here is the pic: 
https://picasaweb.google.com/116591322380497799116/December222012#5824813491341054930 

This is first time I experienced how a transistor blasting in my eyes. It's very sad.